# Link error while trying to use glLoadGen

Tags: c++, opengl

While reading the [OpenGL 4 Shading Language Cookbook](https://books.google.de/books?id=vpluAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=C%2B%2B%20Opengl&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir9pay1Y_cAhWCiqYKHaPPCUUQ6AEITTAG#v=onepage&q=C%2B%2B%20Opengl&f=false), I encountered the [OpenGL Loader Gen](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Home) library and immediately wanted to try it out. I started creating a small example program that you can see underneath.

```
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"
#include "GL/gl_core_4_1.hpp"

namespace engine
{
    class Window
    {
    private:
        const unsigned int width;

        const unsigned int height;

        const char *title;

        const void refresh()
        {
            glfwSwapBuffers(this -> glfwWindow);
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    protected:
        GLFWwindow *glfwWindow;
    public:
        Window(const unsigned int width, const unsigned int height, const char title[]): width(width), height(height), title(title)
        {
            if (glfwInit() != GLFW_TRUE)
            {
                throw "Couldn't initialise the required GLFW library.";
            }
            glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);
            glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
            glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
            glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
            if (this -> glfwWindow)
            {
                throw "Cannot create a secondary window.";
            }
            this -> glfwWindow = glfwCreateWindow(this -> width, this -> height, this -> title, NULL, NULL);
            // This is the crucial line that will stop the program from compiling.
            gl::exts::LoadTest context = gl::sys::LoadFunctions();
            if (!context)
            {
                throw "Couldn't initialse the required GL library.";
            }
            glfwMakeContextCurrent(this -> glfwWindow);
            glfwSwapInterval(GLFW_TRUE);
            if (!glfwWindow)
            {
                glfwTerminate();
                throw "Couldn't create a new initially empty window.";
            }
        }

        const bool await()
        {
            this -> refresh();
            if (glfwWindowShouldClose(this -> glfwWindow))
            {
                glfwDestroyWindow(this -> glfwWindow);
                glfwTerminate();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
}

int main(const int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    engine::Window window(1280, 720, "Foundation");
    while (window.await())
    {
    }
    return 0x00000000;
}
```

My next step was to try compiling the program with the `LLVM` compiler on computer running on the *macOS High Sierra* operating system.

> clang++ -o Application.exec Subdirectory/*.cpp -lglfw -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo

However, during compilation I receive the following unexpected linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "gl::sys::LoadFunctions()", referenced from:
      engine::Window::Window(unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*) in Application-58a670.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is my actual question: *how do I let the program shown above compile using the previously mentioned [OpenGL Loader Gen](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Home) library*?

Comment: To everyone that tried to resolve the issue as well: after compiling the source with `LUA` as shown on the official page, instead of including the `gl_core_x_x.hpp` file, just include the other  `.cpp` file created as well after building successfully completed. I also had to include the following line in the  `LUA` script:  `unpack = table.unpack` right before the last line in the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [the docs](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Home)

> The above command line will generate gl_core_3_3.h and gl_core_3_3.c files. Simply include them in your project; there is no library to build, no unresolved externals to filter through.

You need to run their generator to produce those source files.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I'm relatively new to `C++` and have the following question to you: when I include the library like this:  `#include "gl_core_4_1.hpp"` the program won't compile, however when I include the  `.cpp` file instead, the program complies just fine! Why is that the case?

Comment: There is not enough information to answer that. What’s the error and which generation style did you choose?

Comment: What do you define under a "generation style"?

Comment: The `-style` parameter to the generation script. But what is your error?

Comment: Of course! Now I know what you meant! I actually used `pointer_cpp` when building both files. The only error shown is already inside the question itself. There are no "code" related issues with it. Only the including appears to be "wrong".

Comment: @NiklasSimandi in (your first comment)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51232896/link-error-while-trying-to-use-glloadgen#comment89445821_51233312], you wrote »the program won't compile«. In what way? You should include the *.hpp file and add the *.cpp file to your build system (or the clang call in your case).